# How to fix Failed to resolve: support-core-utils?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

In my application i added some **dependencies** into `buld.gradle` file and when click on **sync** button show me below error :

```
Failed to resolve: support-core-utils
Open File
```

**My build.gradle :**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    //Retrofit, gson
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    //
    compile('ir.approo:helper:0.4.7-SNAPSHOT')
    compile('ir.approo:core:0.4.7-SNAPSHOT')
}
```

**When added this lines show me error :**

compile('ir.approo:helper:0.4.7-SNAPSHOT')
compile('ir.approo:core:0.4.7-SNAPSHOT')

I added below **dependency** into `build.gradle` and click on **sync** but again show me above error :

```
   compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0'
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: I couln't solve the problem. I fixed by moving back from 28 to 27 (appCompat library). No idea why it has problems with 28. It's now OK!